# Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: c#, .net, oledb, 32bit-64bit, jet

I created a windows application developed in .NET 3.5 in a 32 bit Windows 2008 server. When deployed the application in a 64 bit server it shows the error "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine ".

So as a solution to this issue, i have changed the build property of the project to X86, so that it will build in 32 bit mode, and rebuild the project in the 32bit machine. But, the same project uses other DB drivers (DB2, SQL etc.) to connect to other databases. So when i deployed my app again in the 64 bit OS, it throws the exception " Attempted to load a 64-bit assembly on a 32-bit platform. "

I am using the Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 driver to read and write to the Excel (.xls)

Answer (score 285, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem. The issue I described in my question occured basically due to the incompatibility of the *Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 driver* in 64 bit OS.

So if we are using Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 driver in a 64 bit server, we have to force our application to build in in 32 bit mode (This is the answer I found when I did an extensive search for this **known issue**) and that causes other part of my code to break.

Fortunately, now Microsoft has released a 64 bit compatible ***2010 Office System Driver*** which can be used as replacement for the traditional Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 driver. It works both in 32 bit as well as 64 bit servers. I have used it for Excel file manipulation and it worked fine for me in both the environments. <del>But this driver is in **BETA**.</del>

As the 2010 link is no longer available, you can currently download this driver from [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920)

Comment: Also pay special attention to the instructions on that link :)

Comment: I had the same issue. I changed the application configuration to x86, then it worked!

Comment: also i had to change connection string from using Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 to Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0

Comment: Yes, although a 64-bit compatible Access Database Engine is available, it requires that no 32-bit version of MS Office products be already installed on the system (e.g. 32-bit MS Word) which is a big issue. The workaround is that you use 32-bit version of Access Database Engine 2010 and force your .NET application to run in 32-bit mode (e.g. by selecting x86 platform in Configuration Manager). And the proper solution is to replace MS Access with a better alternative.

Comment: noob question: can i distribute this Driver like "within my application" or does every user who wants to use my application have to install it manually?

Comment: The answer to that question is provided by the last word in the article title, "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable". By definition, a redistributable component may be distributed with your application, so long as you add significant value.

Comment: x86 made problems in my otherwise 64-bit environment. So I switched to Mixed Platforms, that did the trick. Thanks for the help!

Comment: How do I include the driver in my application so no installation on user machine is necessary?

Comment: I can confirm: This is the way! I had an old mdb file and after installing the X64 driver and using ACE.OLEDB.12.0 instead of Jet.OLEDB.4.0 I can open the db from a x64 compiled application. Thanks!!

Comment: Hos does one change the connection string? I have never entered one...

Answer (score 133):

If the issue persist in ASP.NET,All I had to do was change the "Enable 32-bit Applications" setting to True, in the Advanced Settings for the Application Pool.

Comment: I was using 64-bit ODBC and this change started to give me database error. I corrected it though. In case someone encounter this too, you will have to install 32-bit ODBC drivers and then create your DSN in that.

Comment: It is quite possible to do this entirely in 64-bit code now. Install the redistributable linked in [neo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1992009/33080), then use the Provider string suggested in [Iqbal's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16117432/33080). Then upvote both of those answers. That's it!

Comment: This fixed the issue for me on Windows Server 2008 R2 after having installed the 32bit [Access DB Engine Redist](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255).

Comment: The downside is that the pool will run in 32-bit mode. We will instead switch to ACE to avoid this.

Answer (score 73):

I have the same problem

> Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local
>   machine

I applied the answer by **neo** but it did not work until I change the provider to **“Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;”** in connection string.

Hope this will help if some one face the same issue.

Comment: This is it! For a 64-bit server, install the [redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) linked by neo (the 64-bit variant, obviously), and then change the provider as specified in this answer, _then_ it'll work.

Comment: You are right romkyns. I already said I applied neo solution, then changes the provider. But thanks your comment makes it more clear. Thanks a lot romkyns

Comment: replaced Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 with Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; in app.config and everything worked.

Comment: I found that this worked, while restricting the app to 32-bit made no difference whatsoever.

Comment: In my case: "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 not registered", :(

Comment: THIS WORKS..... 
you have to install 64 bit version and change connection string to as this Answer.
I tried so many ways, this is the only solution I found. (changing build version did not effect). 
Thank you...

Comment: I have no such thing in app.config

Answer (score 42):

I know it's quite old questions and many persons has answered. but I am summarizing the things for understanding:

If the file extension is xls and OS is 32 bit then only you can use "`Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0`". Microsoft has not released 64 bit version of this driver.

If file extension is xlsx or OS is 64 bit then you must have to use "`Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`". The application compiled in 32/64 bit mode does not impact the selection of driver.

Always install the 64 bit driver of `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` on OS 64 bit. If you have already installed Office 32 bit then you need to run driver from cmd with /passive argument. This hack works till Office 2013 only, Microsoft stopped this workaround from Office 2016 for Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 drivers.

```
AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe /passive
```

[Download drivers Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

```
private void ProcessFile(string path)
{
    string connString = string.Empty;

    if (Path.GetExtension(path).ToLower().Trim() == ".xls" && Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem == false)
        connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
    else
        connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
}
```

If Application is compiled with AnyCPU flag, it will look for 64 bit Access drivers on 64 bit OS and 32 bit access drivers on 32 bit OS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, I am using VS2015 on Windows 10 and using X64. When I changed the project configuration from AnyCPU to X86, the problem went away. I did not have to install any additional drivers.

Comment: @NoChance I think you have already installed Office 64 bit on your machine and it already contains Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 drivers.

Comment: Thx for your reply, I have office 2007 only.

Answer (score 23):

If your application runs on localIIS, You can solve this problem by **enabling 32-bit applications** in AppPool's **Advanced Settings**

[image]

Answer (score 22):

I've the same message, I have a webpage with do on visual studio 2010, I read a file.xls on that page,in my project visual has not any problem, when I put it on my IIS local throw me a **'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine'**
,I fixed that problem next following this steps,

1.-Open IIS
2.-Change the appPool  on **Advanced Settings**
3.-true to **enable to 32-bit application.**

 and that's all

ps.I changed  Configuration Manager to X86 on Active Solution Platform

Comment: This forces your app to run in 32 bit mode.  You need this setting off if you want to be able to avoid the 4GB barrier.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue. I changed the application configuration to `x86`, then it worked!

Comment: how to change this configuration? I have created website type project

Answer (score 8):

I just Changed my Property of project into x64 format

Project---> Properties--->Build--->Target Framework---> X64

Answer (score 8):

We have come across this issue in desktop app.

**Dev Environment:**
Windows 7 Ultimate - 64 bit
.Net Framework 4.5
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0

It has been resolved by changing Platform target to X86 from Any CPU.
Project Properties >> Build >> Platform Target.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue with my desktop application ('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine). I did not have the option to build as a 32 bit app. Hoping this would help others in the same situation.

I did the following and the issue went away:

1. Installed the 64 bit version of [Microsoft Access Database Engine
   2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255), as suggested by neo
2. Changed my provider to Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0

Comment: How and where do you change that? I have no such conn strin anywhere, and I dont work with Office (im using Catfood.Shapefil lib).

Answer (score 3):

Although a more optimal solution is to simply recompile as suggested above, that requires access to the source code.  In my case, I only had the finished .exe and had to use this solution.  It uses `CorFlags.exe` from the .Net SDK to change the loading characteristics of the application.

1. Download the .Net Framework SDK (I personally used [3.5](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3138), but the version used should be at or above the required .Net for your application.
2. When installing, all you need is `CorLibs.exe`, so just check *Windows Development Tools*.
3. After installation, find your `CorFlags.exe`.  For my install of the .Net Framework 3.5 SDK, it was at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Bin`.
4. Open a command prompt and type `path/to/CorFlags.exe path/to/your/exeFile.exe /32Bit+`.

You're done!  This sets the starting flags for your program so that it starts in 32 bit WOW64 mode, and can therefore access microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` with `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` in your connection string

Comment: Why is this not the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

Change in IIS Settings application pool advanced settings.Enable 32 bit application

Answer (score 1):

Just Change the property based on your machine and all have done :-)

Project---> Properties--->Build--->Target Framework---> X64

or

Project---> Properties--->Build--->Target Framework---> X86

Answer (score 1):

I have changed my connection string from

var myConnectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Persist Security Info=True;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=;",gisdbPath);

to this:

var myConnectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Mode=Share Deny None;Data Source={0};user id=Admin;password=;", gisdbPath);

It works fro me never asked for Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0'registered.

Answer (score 0):

**There is indeed no 64 bit version of Jet - and no plans (apparently) to produce one.**

You might be able to use the ACE 64 bit driver: 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=23734

- but I have no idea how that would work if you need to go back to Jet for your 32 bit apps.

However, you may be able to switch the project to 32bit in the Express version (I haven't tried and don't have 2008 installed in any flavour anymore)

- there is a thread here that talks about it: 
  http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/4377.aspx#22601

Maybe it's time to scrap Access databases altogether, bite the bullet and go for SQL server instead?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using VS2013 for Winforms, the below solution worked for me.

- Download : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=23734
- Then Set VS Target Platform to x86.

Answer (score 0):

In older versions of IIS, you will not find `Advance Settings` so to enable `Enable 32-bit Applications` you have to execute the following commands:

**cscript %SYSTEMDRIVE%\inetpub\adminscripts\adsutil.vbs SET W3SVC/AppPools/Enable32bitAppOnWin64 1**

and

**%SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -i**

Reference : [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/894435/en-gb)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same exception while running "SQL Server 2014 Import and Export Data (64-bit)" on my Windows 8.1.

To fix the issue this issue I have done the following

**started SQL Server 2014 Import and Export Data (32-bit) instead of 64-bit** and it is working for me. I haven't changed any IIS setting and not installed any extra software.

Answer (score 0):

I know that I have this problem over and over when I deploy my application on a new server because I'm using this driver to connect to a Excel file. So here it is what I'm doing lately.

There's a Windows Server 2008 R2, I install the Access drivers for a x64 bit machine and I get rid of this message, which makes me very happy just to bump into another.

This one here below works splendidly on my dev machine but on server gives me an error even after installing the latest ODBC drivers, which I think this is the problem, but this is how I solved it.

```
private const string OledbProviderString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\OlsonWindows.xls;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES\"";
```

I replace with the new provider like this below:

```
private const string OledbProviderString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\OlsonWindows.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;';";
```

But as I do this, there's one thing you should notice. Using the .xlsx file extension and Excel version is 12.0.

After I get into this error message *Error: "Could Not Find Installable ISAM"*, I decide to change the things a little bit like below:

```
private const string OledbProviderString =      @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\OlsonWindows.xls;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;';";
```

and yes, I'm done with that nasty thing, but here I got another message *The Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or write to the file 'time_zone'. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data.* which tells me I'm not far away from solving it.

Maybe there's another process that opened the file meanwhile and all that I have to do is a restart and all will take start smoothly running as expected.

Answer (score 0):

go to Start->Run and type cmd
this starts the Command Prompt
(also available from Start->Programs->Accessories->Command Prompt)

type cd .. and press return
type cd .. and press return again (keep doing this until the prompt shows :> )

now you need to go to a special folder which might be c:\windows\system32 or it might be c:\winnt\system32 or it might be c:\windows\sysWOW64
try typing each of these eg
cd c:\windows\sysWOW64
(if it says The system cannot find the path specified, try the next one)
cd c:\windows\system32
cd c:\winnt\system32
when one of those doesn't cause an error, stop, you've found the correct folder.

now you need to register the OLE DB 4.0 DLLs by typing these commands and pressing return after each

regsvr32 Msjetoledb40.dll
regsvr32 Msjet40.dll
regsvr32 Mswstr10.dll
regsvr32 Msjter40.dll
regsvr32 Msjint40.dll

Answer (score -2):

There isn't a 64 bit provider for Jet.  If you want to support multiple DB sources including Jet to Excel you will need at least that part of your application to run in a 32 bit process.

The error you are getting when you compile for x86 is a bit strange.  I can't see how you would end up referencing  64 bit assemblies in this case.

Comment: Anthony, How i can make only some part of a project to run in 32bit mode? All these DB connections, including Excel, will come under one project.
Also i got the error in x86, when i try to run it in the 64 bit OS. I think this is because the DB2 driver installed in the 64bit OS is a 64bit version and when it is refferenced from the application, which is configured to run in 32 bit mode, causes the error.

Comment: If splitting up the project into multipe exes is more hassle than its worth the you are left with only compiling to 32bit.  As to the DB2 issue you would to look for some DB2 experts on this perhaps another DB2 specific question.  Typically things like SQL Server will install both 32 bit and 64 bit providers on a 64 bit machine.

Comment: Thanks Anthony for your comments. 
From doing a lot of search on this issue and from your comments, what i understood is, i have to create the part of the project which process the excel sheet as a separate project and make it compile in 32 bit version.

Comment: Just so people know, A2010 will have 64-bit Jet.

Comment: Thanks David, 2010 do have a 64 bit driver