# Adding an Access 2003 System DSN in Windows 7

Tags: ms-access, windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a Windows 7 ODBC driver for Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013837/is-there-a-windows-7-odbc-driver-for-access)

I'm migrating an Access 2003 app from Windows XP to Windows 7. In the ODBC Data Source Administrator - User or System DSN, when I click on "Add", the only selection is SQL Server. Where/how do I install the ODBC for Access so it's available

Comment: What language are you using to access this Access database file?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently using odbcad32.exe under %WINDIR%\SYSWOW64, you will find all the 32bit drivers.