# How to fix 'The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application' error in PHP

Tags: php, odbc, ms-access-2007

I'm just trying to connect php and ms-access
in administrative tools I can see that there 2 ODBC Drivers 32 and 64 bit so i configured the 32 bit because I can create a New Data Source using the Microsoft access driver. after that I write this code to check if can now connect to my msaccess

```
    $con = odbc_connect("accessdatasource", "root", "" );
    if($con){
        echo "Connected";
    } else {
        echo "Failed";
    }
```

and i got an error that says

> Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application, SQL state IM014 in SQLConnect in C:\xampp\htdocs\connect\index.php on line 7

what could be wrong? I don't get the DSN contains an architecture mismatch

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application. JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895823/the-specified-dsn-contains-an-architecture-mismatch-between-the-driver-and-appli)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP ODBC connect() to Access - architecture mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219897/php-odbc-connect-to-access-architecture-mismatch)