# Can not Open ODBC connection for MSAceess in Windows7 64bit

Tags: c#, ms-access, odbc, 64-bit, windows-7-x64

Can not connect MSAcess through ODBC.
OdbcConnection.Open thrown an exception like

"ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"

code portion is follows:

```
 string connetionString = null;
            OdbcConnection cnn;
            connetionString = (@"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,*.accdb)};Dbq=E:\aa.mdb;Exclusive=1;Uid=Admin;Pwd=;");
 cnn = new OdbcConnection(connetionString);
            try
            {
                cnn.Open();
                MessageBox.Show("Connection Open ! ");
                cnn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
            }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a Windows 7 ODBC driver for Access?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013837/is-there-a-windows-7-odbc-driver-for-access), [Windows 7 64 bit odbc drivers for Ms Access Missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721702/windows-7-64-bit-odbc-drivers-for-ms-access-missing), and several others. Please use the search box at the top right of any page.

Comment: Please pay attntion to your speelling. Wrong spelling makes people trigger-happy.

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string is wrong, this works for me:

```
connetionString = (@"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=E:\aa.mdb;Uid=Admin;Pwd=;");
```

See http://connectionstrings.com