# jet.OLEDB.4.0 provider Error that i get

Tags: c#

i try to install my C# program on Windows 7 64bit

i installed Access too

and i got this error:

```
The Microsoft.jet.OLEDB.4.0 provider is not registered on the local machine
```

that can be the problem ?

thank's in advance

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991643/microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine

Answer (score 2):

Compile and run as 32bit (set options in visual studio from target "Any CPU" to "x86").

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with 64 bit version. Try running your application in 32 bit mode and see if that fixes the problem.