# The 'microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: oledb

I've got this error when I run my asp.net mvc website on IIS7 WINDOWS2008 64
The 'microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

Is their any thing i need to install?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: [Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991643/microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine/1992009#1992009

Answer (score 2):

Similar question:

- [Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991643/microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine)

*The answer there explains that there is only a 32-bit version of the Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 provider, and no plans for a 64-bit version.*

**1-A. One option is to compile your application in 32-bit and use the 32-bit version of Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0.**

1-B. Since you have a web application running on IIS7, you would also need to run your application in a 32-bit application pool:

- [IIS7 Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' Not Registered](http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en/web/thread/2111c297-fab8-482b-9439-53b1464b782e)

**2. The option presented in the answer is to use a new 64-bit provider.  This provider is no longer in Beta.  You would have to modify you project to use the new provider:**

- [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13255)

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd option is by far the best i've used not only does allow to work with new files format it also worked against 32 bit application should one has installed the 64bit version which is common theses days.

Should you be looking in to the future look for "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable"