# Read Excel File from Both x86 and x64

Tags: c#, excel, import

My local PC is installed with Windows7 64bit and Microsoft Excel 2010
But most of my clients' PC are XP Professional Service Pack 3 and Excel 2003

I got this connection string for import data of Excel file

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\MyExcel.xls;Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1";
```

But this throws an error saying that

```
The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.
```

I want my application can read Excel file on both, x86 and x64, architectures.
How can i handle this programmatically without installing extra Excel driver on PC?

I'm thinking to use different connection strings for importing Excel files based on CPU archtiecture.

Is there any better idea?

Comment: Are you hard-coding a connection string? If so, which one and why? Have you considered using a relative path?

Comment: I'm asking a connection string for importing Excel file which works both on x86 and x64 PCs.

Comment: http://http://connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have installed the Jet driver that supports both x86 and x64 on your development system.

[Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991643/microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine)

Answer (score 0):

This is because of a mismatch between compilation configuration in Visual Studio and the ACE version installed on the system. ([Ref: How to read or write excel file using ACE OLEDB data provider?](https://yoursandmyideas.com/2011/02/05/how-to-read-or-write-excel-file-using-ace-oledb-data-provider).)

You can resolve it by making sure that both are same. Compile your app using the x64 bits if 64-bit ACE is installed or use 32-bit ACE.