# 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on this machine

Tags: jet

I am having an issue with using a program that writes information to a Microsoft Access database. The issue is that whenever I try to execute a database query, I get the following error:

[image: Error]

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.InvalidOperationException: The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbServicesWrapper.GetDataSource(OleDbConnectionString constr, DataSourceWrapper& datasrcWrapper)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
   at PA_SHALER_HIGH_SCHOOL.frmAnimalInput.btnSave_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8009 (FX35W81RTMGDR.050727-8000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
PA_SHALER HIGH SCHOOL
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/David/Desktop/PA_SHALER%20HIGH%20SCHOOL.exe
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualBasic
    Assembly Version: 8.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 8.0.50727.8007 (FX35W81RTMGDR.050727-8000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualBasic/8.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8009 (FX35W81RTMGDR.050727-8000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8008 (FX35W81RTMGDR.050727-8000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8007 (FX35W81RTMGDR.050727-8000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8007 (FX35W81RTMGDR.050727-8000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8009 (FX35W81RTMGDR.050727-8000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Remoting
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8012 (FX35W81RTMGDR.050727-8000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Remoting/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.Remoting.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8007 (FX35W81RTMGDR.050727-8000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_64/System.Data/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Transactions
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8007 (FX35W81RTMGDR.050727-8000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_64/System.Transactions/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

I have tried downloading and installing the MS Access database engine thingy (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=13255) but it has not worked. What is the problem? I am using Windows 8.1 Pro x64 and the program was written using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. I can also tell you that the program worked when I was coding it and I can tell you that it works on Windows 7 Enterprise x86 just fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991643/microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by retargeting my project to use a newer version of the .NET Framework. I tried houssam's solution of downloading the Access database engine for 64 bit prior to posting on StackOverflow, but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

you must download Access engine for 64 bit (AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe) from: 
http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/4/3/24375141-E08D-4803-AB0E-10F2E3A07AAA/AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe 
or you can configure your project's target platform to x86 instead of "Any CPU" from:
 Visual studio -> project menu -> youProjectName Properties -> compile tab -> click on Advanced compile options -> target CPU = x86 -> ok ->ok.