# How do i save as Excel file (.xlsb) in Text (.txt) (Tab delimited) format using Excel Interop c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, excel-interop

I want to open Excel file and save as text tab delimited format. How the object in Save As() Set?

Answer (score 0):

here is how you can achieve this:

```
//The connection string to the excel file
   string connstr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0;Data Source=d:\temp\test.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0";
   //The connection to that file
   OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connstr);
   //The query
   string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Feuil1$]";
   //The command 
   OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(/*The query*/strSQL, /*The connection*/conn);
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   conn.Open();
   try
   {
     OleDbDataReader dr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
     StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("D:\\temp\\export.txt");
     if (dr1.Read())
     {
       dt.Load(dr1);
     }

     int iColCount = dt.Columns.Count;

     for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
     {
       sw.Write(dt.Columns[i]);
       if (i < iColCount - 1)
       {
         sw.Write("\t");
       }
     }
     sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
     // Now write all the rows.

     foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
     {
       for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
       {
         if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[i]))
         {
           sw.Write(dr[i].ToString());
         }
         if (i < iColCount - 1)
         {
           sw.Write("\t");
         }
       }
       sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
     }
     sw.Close();
     Console.WriteLine("File is saved");
   }
   catch (OleDbException caught)
   {
     Console.WriteLine(caught.Message);
   }
   finally
   {
     conn.Close();
   }
```

Source : [Msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a6ceb8be-b633-4fff-88e0-1692206e2db2/c-excel-to-text-conversion)

Comment: the message error told "The 'Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine." Did i forget something? @Kayani

Comment: You may need to install this first http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: see this question to resolve this issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991643/microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine