# An application says Microsoft.jet.Oledb 4.0 provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: oledb, provider

I'm.not the developer of that application. I'm the user , I downloaded an application 64bit as they directed . When I try to open the application it says the error Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB4.0 provider not registered on the local machine. I googled and searched in stacks. All the solutions are to the developers.as a user how can I run this application , how do enable/register that provider

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading Microsoft Access Database Engine.

Comment: I tried that too... I installed Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010.

Comment: It didn't help?

Comment: Check this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991643/microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine