# Microsoft.Jet.oledb 4.0 is not registered on local machine Windows 7 64 bit, office 2013 for .mdb file

Tags: c#, .net

I have installed https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255
Still same problem.

While reading .mdb file error occured Microsoft.Jet.oledb 4.0 is not registered on local machine.

Runnnig website on IIS server.

Comment: install both x86 and x64 bit of runtime

Comment: Can you please send me link of runtime for Office 2013 both x86 and x64.

Comment: you already have the link in your question (Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable), after u press the [Download] button, the page will pop another box for u to choose both x86 and x64, you may download both, and install both.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991643/microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

open IIS , Go To application pool of your website. Select Advance Settings , There will be one option : Enable 32 Bit ( second option) , It will start working

Comment: But I have used some DLL that build on 64 bit so if I set App Pool setting Enable 32-bit Applications to true then its create problem for dll.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the 64-bit drier installed? Both?

Also double check your IIS App Pool settings, to be sure you're running the correct 32-bit vs 64-bit settings there.

Comment: Yes I have installed 64 bit Office Redistributable. But I have used some DLL that build on 64 bit so if I set App Pool setting Enable 32-bit Applications to true then its create problem for dll.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from @Iqbal

> change the provider to “Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;” in connection string

Only change I had to do.

[Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991643/microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine/16117432#16117432)