# Unable to read excel from commandline NUnit-Console.exe

Tags: excel

I am executing a automation test for webservices written in C# and I have my test data in the excel spreadsheet. When I am running my test using visual studio to my local  machine then it all works fine. But when I try to run these tests through commandline using `Nunit-Console.exe` command then all the tests fails because of this error.

> [Error] - Unable to read all data from spreadsheet. System.InvalidOperationException: The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

Excel version that I am using is "Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Worksheet (.xls)"

Can you please advise some solution for this.

Comment: Likely to be a 64 vs 32 bit driver issue. See this old post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991643/microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine

Comment: I have change solution configuration to x86 and it works for me. Thanks for your help.