# Database connection lost in Visual Studio when changing .NET Framework

Tags: c#

I created a Windows forms project in C# with Visual Studio 2012 that connects to a MS Access database. When I finished it, I went into project properties and changed the [.NET Framework from 4.5 to 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpQEj.png).

When I changed the .NET Framework, the database connection is lost. I even changed it back to .NET Framework 4.5 and [test connection says is OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtkYh.png) but I can't connect to the database.

My connection string is:

```
string constring = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\libereas\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\kataxorisiOplon\kataxorisiOplon\bin\Debug\resources\data.mdb";
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: So, the test query you've written works okay?  What error(s) are you getting in your subsequent queries?

Comment: there are no error when i run it from visual studio. The dataGridView that loads the db is empty. Even if i try catch the con.Open() it does't find errors. But when i run the code from debug folder says "The Microsofr.jet.OLEDB.4.0 provider is not registered on the local machine

Comment: You sure it's no a version (32/64bit) issue?  It's known to cause compilation issues.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991643/microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine

Comment: 32/64 on what? On 'buld' -> platform target though is says 'any pc'. I have changed many projects that way from 4.5 .net framework to 4.0 but none of them used database connection.

Comment: Yes, change it to 32 bit (probably) as the necessary references will change based on OS architecture.

Comment: Can't believe i lost 2 days for that. That was it. But if i buid it can i run it on a win 64 pc?

Comment: Yes, it will run okay on 64bit machines.  However, if memory is an issue you could run into problems.

Comment: I run into them with SQL Server Management from Microsoft because it's strictly 32bit as well.

Comment: ok thanx can you write that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sure it's not a version (32/64bit) issue? It's known to cause compilation issues. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991643/

Comment: Thank you. I had to change it to 32 bit for it to run.

Comment: They may have a 64bit reference if you really needed it for some reason but 99% of the time it's not worth the effort.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for your time i'll keep that in mind